# Return multiple COUNT fields for distinct values per a unique ID based on two criteria conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, where-clause

I'm trying to work with some logging data in MySQL where I want to be able to tell, per individual, counts of the number of distinct successful requests, distinct unsuccessful requests, non-distinct successful requests, and non-distinct unsuccessful requests that all meet additional global criteria.

Here is a sample of made up data that represents the original table:

```
+--------------+--------+---------------+----------+------+
| request_date | client |    request    | response | site |
+--------------+--------+---------------+----------+------+
| 10/30/2018   | Amy    | RE_food       |      200 | MD   |
| 10/30/2018   | Amy    | RE_food       |      200 | MD   |
| 10/30/2018   | Amy    | RE_transport  |      200 | MD   |
| 10/30/2018   | Amy    | RE_assistance |      404 | MD   |
| 10/30/2018   | Amy    | OA_assistance |      404 | MD   |
| 10/30/2018   | Bob    | RE_food       |      200 | MD   |
| 10/30/2018   | Dan    | RE_food       |      404 | MD   |
| 10/30/2018   | Dan    | RE_food       |      404 | SE   |
| 10/30/2018   | Mike   | RE_transport  |      200 | SE   |
| 10/30/2018   | Sally  | RE_food       |      404 | SE   |
| 10/30/2018   | Sally  | OA_food       |      404 | MD   |
| 10/30/2018   | Zeb    | RE_assistance |      404 | MD   |
| 10/30/2018   | Zeb    | OA_assistance |      404 | MD   |
+--------------+--------+---------------+----------+------+
```

I want to write a query that will return

```
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
| client | unique_OK | unique_404 | total_OK | total_404 |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

where unique means counting only the distinct client, request, response groupings.  it would return the results

```
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
| client | unique_OK | unique_404 | total_OK | total_404 |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
| Amy    |         2 |          1 |        3 |         1 |
| Bob    |         1 |          0 |        1 |         0 |
| Dan    |         0 |          1 |        0 |         1 |
| Mike   |         0 |          0 |        0 |         0 |
| Sally  |         0 |          0 |        0 |         0 |
| Zeb    |         0 |          1 |        0 |         1 |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

(Note that shown above I am showing the clients with 0 counts across all four columns for clarity about the process; it's fine if they are not included in the response.)

I tried queries like this that don't work, but hopefully it makes sense as to what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT client AS person, 
COUNT(DISTINCT request WHERE response = '200') AS unique_OK, 
COUNT(DISTINCT request WHERE response = '404') AS unique_404 
COUNT(WHERE response = '200') as total_OK,
COUNT(WHERE response = '404') as total_404
FROM transactions 
WHERE request like '%RE%' and site = MD and DATE_FORMAT(request_date, '%Y%m%d')='20181030';
```

Comment: "Don't work" will not help us help you.  "Don't work" how?  Wrong result?  No result?  Error out?

Comment: @Eric I just meant to say that I knew it wasn't legal syntax.  Returns syntax error without executing.

Comment: Then include the error in your question.  People can't guess what's on your mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    client,
    count(distinct case when response = 200 then request end) unique_ok,
    count(distinct case when response = 404 then request end) unique_404,
    sum(response = 200) total_ok,
    sum(response = 404) total_404
from mytable
where 
    request like '%RE%'
    and site = 'MD' 
    and request_date = '2018-10-30'
group by client
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4apkG5kayn6uTKXLmwMWnK/0)**:

```
| client | unique_ok | unique_404 | total_ok | total_404 |
| ------ | --------- | ---------- | -------- | --------- |
| Amy    | 2         | 1          | 3        | 1         |
| Bob    | 1         | 0          | 1        | 0         |
| Dan    | 0         | 1          | 0        | 1         |
| Zeb    | 0         | 1          | 0        | 1         |
```

Comment: thanks, works in the original table as well!  "then request" is a little cryptic to me and I'll have to read up on why that works.

Comment: Welcome @lupinist. `case when response = 200 then request end)` returns `request` if `response = 200`, else it returns `null`. Since `count(distinct ...)` ignores `null`, this expression counts distinct values of `request` where `response = 200`.